# Sequelize: Create with Association not working

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have three models: User, Teacher and a Student. A user can either be a teacher or a student depending upon the role.

**Now, I would like to populate the Teacher and the Student model as the User model gets populated. This is the query that I am using which isn't populating the Teacher model. (And the student model as well on the other condition)**

```
const user = await User.create({
        ...userDetails
        include: [Teacher]
})
```

User Model:

```
const User = connObj.define('user', {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
      set (password) {
        const passHash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        this.setDataValue('password', passHash)
      }
    },
    isTeacher: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  })
```

Teacher Model:

```
const Teacher = connObj.define('teacher', {})
```

And the relation is

```
User.hasMany(Teacher)
User.hasMany(Student)
```

I have followed what is mentioned in the Sequelize docs and also other Stack Overflow answers but it just doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Show a content of `userDetails`

Comment: `const userDetails = { username: 'test',
  password: 'tesetpass',
  email: 'test@teacher.com',
  name: 'test teacher',
  role: 'teacher' 
}`
I check role as role === teacher.
I am not sure if this data is the problem because the User table gets populated successfully.

Comment: If you wished to create `Teacher` record along with `User` then you should add `teachers` prop with an array of objects you wish to create.

Comment: Somethine like this ?
`const user = await User.create({...userDetails, teacher: [], include: [Teacher]})`

It didnt work.

Comment: No, You need to indicate as many objects in `teachers` as many teacher records should be created and linked to a created user

Comment: My teacher table only has two columns: id and userId. And I can provide none of them.

Comment: And you shouldn't it. But Sequelize doesn't know how many `Teacher` records do you wish to create along with a given user. So if you wish to create 1 teacher record you should indicate something like `teachers: [{}]`

Comment: any solution yet still having the same problem